# Shared preferences returning String instead of Boolean

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

My application should read boolean values from this default shared preferences file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <boolean android:key="Market"
        android:defaultValue= "true" />
    <boolean android:key="Farmacie"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Musei"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Ristoranti"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Banche"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Bar"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Avvio"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
    <boolean android:key="Background"
        android:defaultValue="true"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the code:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("Avvio", true))
    {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
```

When I run it on my phone, everything seems to be working fine but when I test it on the AVD (Nexus 5, 6.0) I get this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         Process: so2.poifinder, PID: 1861
                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver so2.poifinder.RunAtStartup: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

I also tried to save the values in the XML file as CheckBoxSharedPreference but nothing changed. I was wondering why the emulator returns a String value when parsing the file while my smartphone returns a Boolean value. Should I store everything as a String, just to be sure no Exception will be raised?

**EDIT:**
It was something very stupid: for some reason there was also an older version of the app (with the same name) installed on the emulator and this was the one raising the Exception (because I stored the values as EditText in the XML file). I just had to store a CheckBoxPreference instead of a boolean

Comment: Adding the Elements via the SharedPreferences.Editor works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering why this Exception is raised when I try to read the Preferences for the first time after they've been set in the Main Activity like this: `PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, "myPref", MODE_PRIVATE, R.xml.default_preferences, false);`